# take data from mysql stored with "-"

Tags: mysql

My database is like this:

```
users table
_id_____favorites_____
  1  |    -53-87-96   |
  2  |     -12-54-87  |

images table
_id_____url____________
  1  |    smile.jpg   |
  2  |    lol.jpg     |
```

I stored favorites with seperator "-"; these favorites numbers are images id. When a user logs in they want to see their favorites. How can i write this query?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: do not read second code table stackoverflow says that question did not meet their quality standart so i added some more code

Comment: @synan54 Adding extra code to meet quality standards without any oher relevance is frowned upon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Favorites should be retrieved via a one-to-many relationship. The favorites table should look like

```
id | favorite
---+---------
1  | 53
1  | 87
1  | 96
2  | 12
2  | 54
2  | 87
```

Then you

```
select all from favorites where id = 1
```

Or whatever the id is.

Answer (score 1):

### Never, never, never store multiple values in one column!

That will give you serious problems, like in your case. You should change your database structure. You could add a favorite table

```
favorites table
+--------+------------+
|user_id |favorite_id |
|  1     |  53        |
|  1     |  87        |
|  1     |  96        |
+--------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current schema design is bad, you should properly normalize it into 3-table design.

**User Table**

- UserID (PK)
- UserName
- *other columns...*

**Images Table**

- ImageID (PK)
- ImageLink
- *other columns...*

**Favorites Table**

- UserID
- ImageID
- *other columns...*

Anyway, to answer your question, MySQL's `FIND_IN_SET` will help but you need to replace `-` with `,` using `REPLACE()`.

```
SELECT  a.ID,
        b.url
FROM    users a
        INNER JOIN images b
            ON FIND_IN_SET(b.id, REPLACE(a.favorites, '-', ',')) > 0
WHERE   a.ID = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2575c/2)

Comment: wow thats a good solution thank you i will keep on working to normalize

Comment: @synan54 added a demo.